# Как подключить библиотеку из GitHub в проект Android?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Как мне подклюить [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) в свой LibGDX проект?

Comment: Я уже пробовал через File->Project Structure->Dependencies.  Может руки кривые и не могу там добавить правильно

Comment: Ссылка точка правильная? По вашей ссылке открывается пример от Google с демонстрацией работы с Google Play game services.

Comment: Там же есть инструкция как подрубить ее или я что-то упустил?

Comment: там же на странице есть инструкция. Причем тут dependencies, это не библиотека, а сэмплы.

Comment: Да вот х....н. Я по той инструкции не могу выбрать пункт 4) Select the BasicSamples directory

Comment: В принципе нету такого

Comment: Ошибочка вышла, прошу прощения, ссылка не совсем конкретная.

Comment: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для добавления библиотеки BaseGameUtils в ваш проект необходимо:

1. Клонировать BaseGameUtils на ваш компьютер
2. В Android studio выбрать File > New > Import Module, после чего выбрать BaseGameUtils.
3. В build.gradle добавить

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    // ...
}
```

4. Выполнить Build > Make Project

Все тоже самое но на английском можно найти в [официальной документации](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но сам данной статейки я не нашёл.